# Moving files from UWP storage to NAS

Tags: uwp, unc

I'm writing a TimeLapse photo app. It'll grab an image every 5 mins and store to local storage. Another timer will sweep these files onto a NAS when it's online.

The problem is I can't figure out how to authenticate to a network drive (Synology NAS):

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

StorageFolder networkFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\192.168.1.8\DropZone");
```

Any pointers on how to authenticate to the UNC?

I couldn't find any documentation on authenticating GetFolderFromPathAsync

Comment: There is no API or method mentioned for authentication when access a UNC path based on this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#capabilities-for-accessing-other-locations.  It just needs some capabilities and you might try it.

Comment: I am able to make it work on my Windows 11 machine, but when I deploy to a RaspberryPi every combination I have tried fails. I even tried mapping a network drive and it didn't work.